# Video and Audio Streaming in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, video-streaming

How to achieve audio and video streaming in iOS, is there any free library available with which we can achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

YEs.You can use `MPMediaPlayer` for both audio and video streaming.Reffer `MPMediaPlayer` [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html)

Comment: what if i had to stream video to server.

Answer (score 0):

iOS delivers rich audio and video capabilities. Stream and play full-screen video within your app.

Built-in support for **HTTP live streaming** makes it easy for applications to use standard web servers to stream high-quality audio and video content over the air for playback on iPad, iPhone and iPod touch.

**HTTP live streaming** is designed for mobility and can dynamically adjust playback quality to match the available speed of Wi-Fi or cellular networks. Using `AV Foundation` APIs, HTTP live streaming statistics let you track the popularity of streams and measure various performance metrics.\

See more details here : [developer.apple - Live streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own code for that, and I'd be happy to share it with you. Check out this video demo I made of my project streaming video from one device to another:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mWyZ1z55chw?rel=0" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I used the screen recorder (iOS 11.2) to record my app running on the devices. That's what's causing the  occasional stutter on the receiving end (the screen recorder was recording video as my app was trying to display it at the same time).

Anyway, if this is what you're looking for, let me know and I'll get you started.

Can't see the video? https://youtu.be/mWyZ1z55chw

Answer (score 0):

I posted code that streams audio between two iOS devices at:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tKgVl0X92SYvgpvbljRzilXNQ6iBcjqM

The app uses AudioUnit to record and playback microphone input and speaker output, NSNetServices to connect two iOS devices on your network, and NSStreams to send an audio stream between the devices.

It requires the latest Xcode 9 beta release to compile, and the latest iOS 11 beta release to run it.

NOTE | A log entry for each method call and event is displayed in a textfield that encompasses the entire screen; there is no interactive interface—no buttons, etc. After installing the app on two iOS devices, simply launch it on both devices to automatically connect to your network and start streaming audio.

[image]